# feature matching + homography

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have followed the tutorials on opencv in python. I am using OpenCV 3.2 and Python 3.6.1. The code was written like this:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10

img1 = cv2.imread('test.jpg',0)
img2 = cv2.imread('hanapin_mo.jpg',0)

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, k = 2)

good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance <0.7*n.distance:
        good.append(m)

if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC, 5.0)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    h,w,d = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

    img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)], True, 255, 3, cv2.LINE_AA)

else:
    print("Not enough matches are found - {}/{}".format(len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT) )
    matchesMask = None

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,250,0),
                   singlePointColor = None,
                   matchesMask = matchesMask,
                   flags = 2)

img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, **draw_params)

plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'),plt.show()
```

As I run the module, an error occured:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Albert Eli Reyes/Desktop/SIFT/SIFT.py", line 35, in 
    h,w,d = img1.shape
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

```
    h,w,d = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

    img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)], True, 255, 3, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

What does it mean when it says "not enough values to unpack"? And what should I do to make it run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shape function outputs a tuple of two values only. You are trying to get three values whereas the function returns two values only

```
h,w = img1.shape
```

The above would work

Comment: I have tried that part but it gives me an error like this:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Albert Eli Reyes/Desktop/SIFT/SIFT_2.py", line 50, in <module>
    img3 = cv2.drawMatchesKnn(img1, kp1, img2, kp2, good, None, **draw_params)
SystemError: <built-in function drawMatchesKnn> returned NULL without setting an error

Comment: That's a whole other problem. Ask another question for that. The traceback you gave in the question is caused the problem I mentioned above.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @AlbertReyes the answer is correct, but for future use, just simply use `h, w = img1.shape[:2]`. That way if the image *does* have multiple channels, you're only grabbing the first two dimensions and not the number if channels, and if the image is just grayscale, it gives you the same result as `h, w = img1.shape`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this means that `img1.shape` returns only two values. So if you remove the `d` variable initialization, the code should work as I don't see you using it in your code anyway.

```
h, w = img1.shape
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @AlbertReyes you're welcome, sorry for the duplicate